# How to registering for NSNotification from a Struct?

Tags: swift, struct, nsnotifications

My app is written in Swift and needs to register for audio interruption notifications. I am trying to set up an object to handle this and want to avoid reference types, so am trying to use a Struct.

```
struct AudioInterruptionsManager {

    func registerForNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleInterruptionNotification), name: AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification, object: AVAudioSession.sharedInstance())
    }


    @objc func handleInterruptionNotification(_ notification: NSNotification) {

    }
}
```

The compiler complains: `Add '@objc' to expose this instance method to Objective-C`, but when I do it complains: `@objc can only be used with members of classes, @objc protocols, and concrete extensions of classes`

I understand why the compiler is complaining, but would prefer not to use a class. So my question is: how can I register for NSNotifications from within a Struct, passing in selectors defined in that struct?

Comment: You can use `addObserver(forName:object:queue:using:)` instead which handle the notification within a closure and not another method (through selector)

Comment: @Larme, yes, that worked. Post the answer and i'll mark it correct.